# Sql query can not handle quotation marks

Tags: mysql, d, vibed

I try to achieve a small blog application using vibe.d. I have a form in this adress

[http://localhost:8888/gönderiler/oluştur](http://localhost:8888/g%C3%B6nderiler/olu%C5%9Ftur)

User inputs post title and body. Than these information are stored in a database. Until now so far so good.

Let's say the user inputs a string with a quotation mark like this:

> deneme'miz

Than sql query becomes like this:

> INSERT INTO gonderiler (kullanici_no, baslik, icerik, created_at,
>   updated_at) VALUES (1, 'Deneme', 'deneme'miz', '2017-09-25 12:29:30',
>   '2017-09-25 12:29:30')

As you'd see there is 3 quotation mark signs.

```
    auto başlık = this.başlık_.replace("'","\'");
    auto içerik = this.içerik_.replace("'","\'");

    logInfo("%s %s", başlık, içerik);

    auto sqlKomutu = "INSERT INTO gonderiler (kullanici_no, baslik, icerik, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (1, '"
                     ~ başlık ~
                     "', '"
                     ~içerik ~
                     "', '"
                     ~ zaman ~
                     "', '"
                     ~ zaman ~
                     "')";
```

I tried to replace ' characters with \' but I think it doesn't work.

A friend of mine suggested using these characters.

> `merhaba "dünya"`

But this time I get an error like this:

> MySQL error: Unknown column 'deneme' in 'field list'

**Update : solved**

I putted double quotation marks as suggested.

```
    auto başlık = this.başlık_.replace("'",`''`);
    auto içerik = this.içerik_.replace("'",`''`);
```

Comment: Error has nothing to do with quotes. And localhost has name with reason. It is *LOCAL HOST* meaning you have access to it *locally*. We cannot access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an another quotation mark next to it, like so:

> 'deneme''miz'

If that doesn't work ,just put double quotation marks

> "deneme'miz"